# Density Function of $F\left(Y_1\right)+F\left(Y_2\right)$

Tags: probability-distributions

I came across a question which stated:

> Suppose $Y_1,Y_2,...$ are independently and identically distributed random variables with common distribution function $F$. Then find the pdf of $$U=F\left(Y_1\right)+F\left(Y_2\right)$$

From what I understood of the question, I proceeded as follows (which, I assume, is not correct as I couldn't understand the question properly):

I tried to find the CDF of $U$ and I wrote this
$$\begin{align}P\left(U\leq u\right)&=P\left(F\left(Y_1\right)+F\left(Y_2\right)\leq u\right)\\
&=\int_0^1P\left(F\left(Y_1\right)+y_2\leq u\right)\cdot P\left(F\left(Y_2\right)\leq y_2\right)\cdot dy_2\\
&=\int_0^1\left(F\left(Y_1\right)\leq u-y_2\right)\cdot\left(F\left(Y_2\right)\leq y_2\right)\cdot dy_2
\end{align}$$
I cannot go any further and am confused as to how this problem can be done. Any suggestions and hints will be very much helpful.

> Some thoughts crept into my mind as I was writing this down here:
> Suppose I take another random variable (say $X$) such that I can write the above integral as
> $$\int_0^1\left(P\left(X\leq Y_1\right)\leq u-y_2\right)\cdot\left(P\left(X\leq Y_2\right)\leq y_2\right)\cdot dy_2$$
> But I still cannot figure out anything...

Upon a request, I'm uploading a picture of the question here:
[image: Q2]

Comment: Is there anything in the context of the problem making $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ continuous random variables?  Or their cdf $F$ a continuous function?

Comment: @kimchilover Unfortunately, there is no such information given

Comment: Can you give a link to the original text?

Comment: @kimchilover Actually, this question was given in one of my class assignments a long time back and I had submitted it already (of course I couldn't do this problem). I can upload the screenshot of the question.

Comment: @kimchilover I've uploaded the picture

Comment: With this continuity assumption your problem is trivially covered by the ["Probability integral transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_integral_transform) ; without it, your problem is not solvable with the given data.

Comment: @kimchilover can you please formulate some hints and write them down in the answer? I couldn't do it properly

Comment: @DebarthaPaul: it seems that what you have is the sum of two independent uniformly distributed random variables in $(0,1)$; the resulting distrubution is the tent distribution over $(0,2)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It your random variables are continuous random variables then the [Probability integral transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_integral_transform) kicks in.  The result is, if $X$ is continuous, then the random variable $Z=F(X)$, where $F$ is the distribution function for $X$, is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$.

If your $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are continuous, the distribution of your $U$ is the that of the sum of two independent $U[0,1]$ random variables, as Oliver Diaz guessed in a comment.

If your $Y_i$ are not continuous, that is, if there exists a number $a$ such that $P(Y_1=a)>0$, then the above answer is wrong, and the correct answer depends on details of the distribution of the $Y_i$.

Comment: Okk...I get it now...

Answer (score 1):

Let $V:=F(Y)$, where $F$ is the distribution of $Y$. Then $V$ is a random variable taking values in $(0,1)$. For simplicity, assuming that $F$ is strictly monotone and continuous

$P[V\leq v]=P[F(Y)\leq v]=P[Y\leq F^{-1}(v)]=F(F^{-1}(v))=v$

For more general distriutions, you may use the [quantile function](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3763555/121671) $Q(q):=\inf\{x:F(x)\geq q\}$ which works like an inverse for $F$.