# Derive the distribution of $V=-\beta\sum_{i=1}^\alpha\log_e{F\left(Y_i\right)}$

Tags: probability-distributions

This was a part question to what I posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4085757/697421) and it went like this:

> Suppose $Y_1,Y_2,...$ are independently and identically distributed random variables with common distribution function $F$. For any positive integers $\alpha$ and $\beta$, derive the distribution of
> $$V=-\beta\sum_{i=1}^\alpha\log_e{F\left(Y_i\right)}$$

I proceeded with the following assumption (and as suggested by Oliver Diaz and @kimchilover in the tagged question), that **$Y_i$'s are continuous random variables**. So, $$X_i=F\left(Y_i\right)\sim U\left[0,1\right]$$
I defined $Z_i=\log_e{X_i}$. Thus, $Z_i\in\left(-\infty,0\right]$. The pdf of $Z_i$ comes out as follows:
$$\begin{align}f_{Z_i}{\left(z_i\right)}&=f_{X_i}{\left(e^{z_i}\right)}\cdot \frac{d}{dz_i}e^{z_i}&,z_i\leq0\\
&=e^{z_i}&,z_i\leq0
\end{align}$$
I then proceeded to find the pdf of $A_i=-\beta Z_i$. (Thus, $A_i\in\left[0,\infty\right)$)
$$\begin{align}
f_{A_i}{\left(a_i\right)}&=f_{Z_i}{\left(-\frac{a_i}{\beta}\right)}\cdot\frac{d}{da_i}\left(-\frac{a_i}{\beta}\right)&,a_i\geq0\\
&=-\frac{e^{-a_i/\beta}}{\beta}&,a_i\geq0
\end{align}$$
But this is not a valid pdf. I'm stuck here thinking as to where I went wrong. My plan of action was this: I would find the pdf of $-\beta Z_i$, and then, I'll try to find the distribution of $V=-\beta\sum_{i=1}^\alpha Z_i$ using the mgf of $A_i$.

Can somebody point out the mistake in my process? Also, any hints and alternative methods are very much welcome.

Comment: [Gamma Distribution out of sum of exponential random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/655302/gamma-distribution-out-of-sum-of-exponential-random-variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just forgot to take the absolute value of the derivative term; see [change of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Scalar_to_scalar). The correct density is what you had, without the minus sign on the left, which ends up being an exponential distribution.

Comment: Oh right...I completely overlooked it...Thanks btw...